# Authentication Code Error

Tags: authentication

Here is a link to a php script needed to authenticate a username and password granting to Uberflip. suggested code can be seen [here](https://support.uberflip.com/forums/64328/entries/54720)

It's supposed to echo a variable for authentication purposes but instead seems to be giving the following error.

> Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
>   resource in /home/healthev/public_html/journal/verify_subscribers.php
>   on line 8 username/password combo not found

Here is my understanding of how the code should be. Can someone provide feedback as to where I might be going wrong?

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "database_user_name", "database_password");
mysql_select_db("database_name");

$sql = "SELECT count * FROM 'subscribers' where user_login='" . $_POST['user_login'] . "' AND user_pass='" . $_POST['user_pass'] . "' LIMIT 1";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$count = mysql_result($result,0); 

if($count==1){
echo "welcome!";
}

else {

echo "username/password combo not found";

}

?>
```

Comment: The warning suggests that `$result` did not have a valid value in it (the `mysql_query` must have come back empty). Note - it just warned you about that, it wasn't an "error", and your script continued to the `echo`. You can turn the warning off by adding `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` at the start of your script - do this only after you are satisfied you understand the warnings fully.

Comment: I assume `datavase_name` in line 3 is not an error, just a placeholder? I would have expected `database_name` or some such.

Comment: As a debug, you might do `echo $sql` before running the query, to make sure everything looks as you expect.